# MATLAB Invalid MEX-file error: missing symbol invalid_argument

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc, mex, linker-errors

I have this problem where MATLAB (R2017a) fails loading a certain MEX-file:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/travis/local/lib/acadosMEX.mexa64': 

Missing symbol '_ZdlPvm' required by '/home/travis/local/lib/acadosMEX.mexa64'
Missing symbol '_ZNSt13runtime_errorC1EPKc' required by '/home/travis/local/lib/acadosMEX.mexa64'
Missing symbol '_ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1EPKc' required by '/home/travis/local/lib/acadosMEX.mexa64'.
```

Running `ldd` on that MEX-file gives me

```
> ldd $HOME/local/lib/acadosMEX.mexa64

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe3fab2000)
libmex.so => not found
libmx.so => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9adb90a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9adb5f8000)
libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f9ad9def000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f9ad9ac7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9ad97c1000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9ad93f9000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9ad91e1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000056477b9a3000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9ad8fc3000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f9ad8d84000)
```

Now if I `grep _ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1EPKc`:

```
> nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep _ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1EPKc
000000000008b520 T _ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1EPKc
```

so the symbol is definitely there; thus I set my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to that directory, i.e. `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` (this should not be necessary, right?).

I should also say that I try all of this with `g++-5` (`g++-6` gives same error), but with `g++-4.9` it works as required.

Is all of this the cause that MATLAB does not support `g++>=5` [(link)](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html)? Or is there still some way of making it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.html), MATLAB 2017a only supports gcc-4.9, not 5 or 6. Recompiling with the supported compiler solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with missing symbols on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) as well. In my case, instead of calling Matlab directly from the terminal (`matlabroot/bin/matlab`), I use the following script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
matlab $@
```

This resolved my issues with missing symbols, but I don't know if we had the same issue to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: *I think this does not answer the full question but might help resolving it. I would have liked to post it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet...*

Referring to:

> so the symbol is definitely there; thus I set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to that directory, i.e. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (this should not be necessary, right?).

According to this [instructions on the Matlab page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-on-unix-operating-systems.html), you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at **runtime** to point to whatever directories you want to be linked to. That might be the reason, why `libmex.so` and `libmx.so` are not found. I think the same applies to `libstdc++.so.6`?